# Sorting an STL vector on two values

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, vector

How do I sort an STL vector based on two different comparison criterias? The default sort() function only takes a single sorter object.

Comment: Can you elaborate more ? What criteria you want ?

Comment: I am sorting a list of objects with two different properties: distance and importance. One of these properties' comparison (higher importance) overrides the other (closer distance). So say if one object's importances is 1 and the other's is 0, it will be sorted higher than the second one even if the distance is larger. I can't figure out a way to do it with just one comparison.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to combine the two criteria into one. 
Heres an example of how you'd sort a struct with a first and second field 
based on the first field, then the second field.

```
#include <algorithm>

struct MyEntry {
  int first;
  int second;
};

bool compare_entry( const MyEntry & e1, const MyEntry & e2) {
  if( e1.first != e2.first)
    return (e1.first < e2.first);
  return (e1.second < e2.second);
}

int main() {
  std::vector<MyEntry> vec = get_some_entries();
  std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare_entry );
}
```

NOTE: implementation of `compare_entry` updated to use code from [Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415784/nawaz).

Comment: +1, Straight forward. I thought the same way. But still doubt if the OP is thinking in the same lines.

Comment: Great, that worked, thank you! I forgot the if( e1.first == e2.first ) part, so it was failing for me.

Comment: @Michael: I added another implementation of `compary_entry` function. Hope its okay with you. :-) +1 BTW.

Comment: +1 Nawaz - I like that change. I was sure it could be a little neater .. and you got it perfect.

Comment: I personally prefer `return e1.first != e2.first ? e1.first < e2.first : e1.second < e2.second;`, but each to their own ;-). Separately, if the types support a single query indicating less-than, equals or greater-than (like `strcmp`), this can sometimes be significantly more efficient: `switch (e1.first.cmp(e2.first)) { case -1: return true; case 0: return e1.second < e2.second; case 1: return false; }` (assuming -1/0/1 values, some cmps just promise -ve/0/+ve and the implementation varies accordingly).