# OpenCv with Objective c Semantic Issue

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

Hi i am new to Opencv and i try to integrate square.cpp with opencv this is working fine. Now i want to sort squares type is "vector>"  based on "Y". I got this link [How to Sort Vector of Points Based on a Y-Axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796732/how-to-sort-vector-of-points-based-on-a-y-axis)
and include  now it gives following error.

*" No matching function for call to object of type 'myClass'"*

This the code i am wrote:

```
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

struct sortClass
{
    public:
    bool operator()(cv::Point pt1, cv::Point pt2) { return (pt1.y < pt2.y);}

} classObj;

static Vector<Point> findHeader(vector<vector<Point> >& squares)

{
    Vector<Point> Header;

std::sort(squares.begin(), squares.end(), classObj);

for( size_t i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++ )
{
    cout <<"sorted ==>"<<squares[i] <<endl;

}
return Header;
}
```

Comment: It might help to see the actual code where the error occurs...

Comment: i wrote the same code in above link but i wrote in my CVsquare.cpp class.

Comment: Error says myClass all the code I see says sortClass.

Comment: Ya i renamed from myClass to sortClass.