# Sort a std::vector by type

Tags: c++, sorting, inheritance

I was watching http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Writing-Quick-Code-in-Cpp-Quickly and around min 36, they talk about the benefits of sorting a collection by the type of its elements if you are going to be calling virtual methods on them.

So given

```
class Base {};
class Der1 : public Base {};
class Der2 : public Base {};
class Der3 : public Base {};

vector<Base *> myVector;
```

How could you sort `myVector` in such a way that the elements of each type are all adjecent?

Is there any way to do that without using a virtual function in order to indentify each derived type? (Maybe using `typeid`?)

Comment: Herb Sutter's recent [Build 2014 talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661) also covers this sort of optimization. It was a great watch, as usual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) for this. You constructing one from a `type_info` object that's returned from `typeid` operator. It's a class with overloaded relational operators with well defined ordering, so that it is useful as a key type in associative containers and alike.

Here's an example:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual const char* who() = 0;
};
struct D1 : Base { const char* who() { return "D1\n"; } };
struct D2 : Base { const char* who() { return "D2\n"; } };
struct D3 : Base { const char* who() { return "D3\n"; } };

int main()
{
    std::vector<Base*> vec { new D2, new D1, new D3, new D3, new D1, new D2 };
    std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    [](const Base* p1, const Base* p2)
    {
        return
            std::type_index(typeid(*p1)) <
            std::type_index(typeid(*p2));
    });

    for (auto p : vec) { std::cout << p->who(); }
}
```

The output is:

```
D1
D1
D2
D2
D3
D3
```

Comment: Worth noting that it works just as well with smart pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

You specify the comparison function. For more details on that, see for example [Sorting an STL vector on two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771374/sorting-an-stl-vector-on-two-values).

Inside the comparison function you can write whatever you want. It can compare whatever properties of your objects. In particular, it can compare one specific value obtained via a virtual function, such as `getType()`, which may return 1 in `Der1`, 2 in `Der2` and 3 in `Der 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a virtual function, say `prio` which returns the priority (an `int`) among the types; `prio` would be suitably implemented in the derived classes. Then implement a comparator which would evaluate `prio` on two instances of `Base` to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

These are just possibilities, there is not one true answer to this.

### Sorting?

The main problem of sorting is finding a key upon which to sort. This is "phase 1", if you want. Phase 2 is using a generic sorting from the standard library and is often easier than phase 1.

### Keying

One possibility is to use `typeid` / `type_info`.

Instances of `type_info` define `operator ==` and `operator !=`, as well as a `hash_code` member function.

### Sorting

Use a generic sort algorithm from the standard algorithm. As the key for sorting you could use e.g. the value returned from the `hash_code` function.