# Static variable and virtual function in a class to implement the predicate for sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, object, static

Using a static variable and virtual function to implement the predicate in a sort() function for polymorphic class object sorting. Is this solution efficient?

Example below:

```
// Here we've got virtual function that return a static variable
// and each derived class has a separate unique static

class Base {
    protected:
        virtual const int &GET_ID const { return BASE_ID; }
    private:
        static const int BASE_ID = 0;
}

class Derived : public Base {
    private:
        const int &GET_ID const { return DERIVED_ID; }
        static const int DERIVED_ID = 1;
}

class Derived2 : public Base {
    private:
        const int &GET_ID const { return DERIVED2_ID; }
        static const int DERIVED2_ID = 2;
}


// We can then construct a predicate for the sort function to
// sort a list of polymorphic object

bool compare (Base *base1, Base *base2) {
    return base1->GET_ID() < base2->GET_ID();
} 

std::sort(containerOfBasePtr.begin(), containerOfBasePtr.end(), compare);
```

I know that it can be done by using non-static protected member but it required more memory allocation for each object.

Comment: You better not use all uppercase identifiers, unless you want to spend endless hours braking your head on some strange error

Comment: It's perfectly OK to use static constant member when you need a constant. (It's probably not so good idea to sort by polymorphic type, why would you need it?)

Comment: It's just a challenge, thought I might be running into such problem one day. I still very new to OOP so, I know nothing.

Comment: You can save yourself the trouble of writing `GET_ID` in every class by using [`type_index`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085715/sort-a-stdvector-by-type/23085880#23085880) - that is, if you don't require specific relative ordering between your classes.

Answer (score 0):

"Efficient" is a relative term. But if you do not wish to have any extra memory usage, then using a virtual function or `type_index` are the only options I can think of.

On the other hand perhaps this could be solved in an entirely different way if we knew more about the problem context. One potential alternative would be to store different objects in entirely different containers, indexed by an `unordered_map`.